# Why do I get "ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended" error ( execute immediate )?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I created a function and it uses a dynamic sql:

```
create function check_ref_value
(
    table_name varchar2,
    code_value number,
    code_name  varchar2
) return number is
    l_query varchar2(32000 char);
    l_res   number;
begin
    l_query := '
        select sign(count(1))
        into :l_res
        from '|| table_name ||'
        where '|| code_name ||' = :code_value
    ';

    execute immediate l_query
    using in code_value, out l_res;

    return l_res;
end;
```

But when I try to use it I get an exception "ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended"
What is wrong with this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ... INTO ... USING ...` to get the return value and `DBMS_ASSERT` to raise errors in the case of SQL injection attempts:

```sql
create function check_ref_value
(
    table_name varchar2,
    code_value number,
    code_name  varchar2
) return number is
    l_query varchar2(32000 char);
    l_res   number;
begin
    l_query := 'select sign(count(1))'
            || ' from  ' || DBMS_ASSERT.SIMPLE_SQL_NAME(table_name)
            || ' where ' || DBMS_ASSERT.SIMPLE_SQL_NAME(code_name)
            || ' = :code_value';
    execute immediate l_query INTO l_res USING code_value;

    return l_res;
end;
/
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE abc (a, b, c) AS
SELECT 1, 42, 3.14159 FROM DUAL;
```

Then:

```sql
SELECT CHECK_REF_VALUE('abc', 42, 'b') AS chk FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | CHK |
> | --- |
> | 1 |

And:

```sql
SELECT CHECK_REF_VALUE('abc', 42, '1 = 1 OR b') AS chk FROM DUAL;
```

Raises the exception:

> ```
> ORA-44003: invalid SQL name
> ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_ASSERT", line 160
> ORA-06512: at "FIDDLE_UVOFONEFDEHGDQJELQJL.CHECK_REF_VALUE", line 10
> ```

---

As for your question:

> What is wrong with this code?

Using `SELECT ... INTO` is only valid in an SQL statement in a PL/SQL block and when you run the statement via `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` it is executed in the SQL scope and not a PL/SQL scope.

You can fix it by wrapping your dynamic code in a `BEGIN .. END` PL/SQL anonymous block (and reversing the order of the bind parameters in the `USING` clause):

```sql
create function check_ref_value
(
    table_name varchar2,
    code_value number,
    code_name  varchar2
) return number is
    l_query varchar2(32000 char);
    l_res   number;
begin
    l_query := '
      BEGIN
        select sign(count(1))
        into :l_res
        from '|| DBMS_ASSERT.SIMPLE_SQL_NAME(table_name) ||'
        where '|| DBMS_ASSERT.SIMPLE_SQL_NAME(code_name) ||' = :code_value;
      END;
    ';

    execute immediate l_query
    using out l_res, in code_value;

    return l_res;
end;
/
```

*(However, that is a bit more of a complicated solution that just using `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ... INTO ... USING ...`.)*

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=359323c562b5bdf84b9e9d8a49a5f00b)*